# What are general best practices for deploying mailman so it can run unattended?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailman-gem

I get mail with `gem mailman` but after working for a while it either hangs or dies.

I have it running in the loop already because of periodical connection error:

```
begin
  Mailman::Application.run
rescue IOError
  retry
end
```

But this is not enough, sometimes it just freezes and I (revive it with Ctrl-C)[https://github.com/titanous/mailman/issues/106] (it runs in `screen`). But after running for while it spat out a new `Net::IMAP::NoResponseError` so I rescue from two errors:

```
rescue IOError, Net::IMAP::NoResponseError
```

What are best practices to run mailman unattended? Is there a list of errors I should rescue from?

**Update**

Today it crashed with some `Undefined method logout for NilClass` in `imap.rb`. Is there a better way of processing incoming emails?